# Where Do I Find sockets_wrapper.h

Tags: micro-ros

Officially supported boards
The officially supported boards are those which have been carried out or tested officially, and to which LTS is guaranteed.  This a joke there is NO support for support for Renesas EK RA6M5 and e2studio.

How obvious is what I'm looking for?  Try searching you archives and find the missing files from 2022.

The package is supplying it's own copy of the the freeRTOS but the amazon-freertos which is in the includes is grayed-out and not part of the distribution.

```
 …/src/wifi_transport_freeRTOS.c:16:10: fatal error: sockets_wrapper.h: No such file or directory
16 | #include “sockets_wrapper.h”
```

[image]

Comment: please update your previous question, instead of writing another ... https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/110203/getting-micro-ros-examples-to-run-on-renesas-ek-ra6m5

Comment: It says:  Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.

Comment: https://github.com/renesas/fsp/releases?page=2

Comment: These are supposed to have LTS but are broken by:Updated FreeRTOS
Secure sockets has been removed. There is no direct replacement.
Cellular and FreeRTOS+TCP still have basic socket APIs (no TLS). WiFi has no "public" socket APIs any longer.
AWS MQTT/HTTP Client modules which were marked as deprecated have been completely removed.

Comment: `It says: Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.` ... it says mora than that ... please read the whole message